# LGA1151 physical dimensions?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, case, processor-socket

I'm designing my own PC case and I need to find the physical dimensions (height specifically) of the LGA1151 socket with a CPU installed as I'm dealing with some low clearance heatsinks.

I was able to find this [LGA1150 socket application guide](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/guides/4th-gen-core-lga1150-socket-guide.pdf) which showed this information:

> Integrated Stackup Height (mm) From Top of Board to Top of IHS: 7.781 ± 0.335 mm

However, I can't for the life of me find the same guide for the LGA1151. Does anyone have an LGA1151 mobo and CPU sitting around that they can put together and measure with calipers? In short I need the dimensions from the top of the motherboard to the top of the CPU's heatspreader/lid. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The difference between 1150 and 1151 is pin design, not socket size. Sources report the same coolers work for both.

Comment: @music2myear thanks for the answer. If you can repost it as such I can mark it as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the 1150 and 1151 sockets is PIN design to support new CPU features, not socket size or geometry.

Intel offers the documentation for the 1150 chip when you search for 1151 information.

Coolers for one of these sockets are fully compatible with the other.

CPUs, however, are specific to one or the other. A CPU for the 1150 socket will not fit the 1151 socket, and vice versa.

From here: http://www.cpu-world.com/Sockets/Socket_1151_H4_LGA1151.html

> The socket LGA1151 has the same width and height as socket 1150.
>   However, the sockets are not interchangeable, and the socket 1150
>   (Haswell) processors will not physically fit into the socket 1151, and
>   vice versa. Socket 1150/1155/1156 fan/heatsinks, however, can be with
>   the socket 1151.

Other references:

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/guides/4th-gen-core-lga1150-socket-guide.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1151